# Minimum number of vertices in an r-regular graph with no triangles and squares

Tags: graph-theory

> Given a graph $G = (V,E)$, $r-\text{regular}$, with no triangles/squares (no cycles of length $3$ or $4$,) prove that $|V(G)| \geq r^2 +1 $

I'll be more than happy to get a direction, thanks!

Comment: Pick a vertex $a$. How many neighbours in common can two neighbors of $a$ have?

Comment: Well, since we have no $3$ or $4$ lenghted cycles, they surely can not have $1$ neighbour in common as that would give a $4$ lengthed cycle. and they surely can not be connected because that will give a $3$ lenghted cycle.
Then it's $0$ neighbours in common?

Comment: And if so, that means that there is $a$, and $r$ neighbours, and each of those r neighbours MUST have some other distinct $r$ neighbours... so it is bigger than $1 + r\cdot r = 1 + r^2$.
Correct?

Comment: Looks good to me :-)

Comment: Please post your comment as a solution (as a hint) so I can accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the OP has solved the problem, I'll post a solution.

Pick a vertex $a$. If $x$ and $y$ are two neighbors of $a$, then $a$ is their only common neighbour (or we'd have a 4-cycle). So for each neighbor $x$ of $a$ we get $k-1$ vertices at distance two from $a$, and these sets of size $k-1$ are pairwise disjoint (or we'd have a 4-cycle).

So we have $a$, its $k$ neighbours, and $k(k-1)$ vertices at distance two from $a$, adding up to $1+k+k^2-k=1+k^2$ vertices as a lower bound.

Comment: Thank you so much. I like the way people on mathexchange almost always give hints rather than full solutions, it just prepares me more and more for the exams and makes me understand better, by getting hints and trying to conclude things.
Thank you again.